# Python Link TKinter distribution at runtime

Tags: python, tkinter

How can I link to a non-default Tkinter (Tk/Tcl) distribution at runtime? The following will link automatically to the default Tkinter. I am on macOS and have custom Tk.Frameworks and Tcl.Framework. I want to be able to link to them when I run my script.

```
import tkinter as tk

root= tk.Tk()

canvas1 = tk.Canvas(root, width = 300, height = 300)
canvas1.pack()

def hello ():  
    label1 = tk.Label(root, text= 'Hello World!', fg='blue', font=('helvetica', 12, 'bold'))
    canvas1.create_window(150, 200, window=label1)
    
button1 = tk.Button(text='Click Me', command=hello, bg='brown',fg='white')
canvas1.create_window(150, 150, window=button1)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Are you looking for the `master` parameter ?

Comment: It depends on the Python and Tcl/Tk versions. Mostly you have to recompile the Python.